# EDMX Entities not populating data

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, poco, edmx

I am working on a project where I am using Entity Framework.

There is a very strange problem I came across.
I am getting the `User` table information via EDMX which has relation with a `Contacts` table (through `UserID` column).

Now, `User` collection has retrieved `ContactID` and it should also retrieve `Contact` information for all the `Users` whereas the `Contact` entity is populated for some of the `User`s and for others it is `NULL`. But, if I check the value in `ContactID` it is available but `Contact` entity is `NULL` for some Users. I never faced this kind of issue. Any suggestions shall be highly apppreciated......

Comment: I guess you have lazy loading.. please post the code where you try to load the user.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure the keys and associations are properly set up.
If you suspect that's the case, read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) article thoroughly.

---

Then choose from one of the following options:

**Include references in your query:**

```
var query = context.Contacts
              .Include(c => c.User)
              .SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserID == userID);
```

**Enable Lazy Loading**
Another option is explicitly enabling lazy-loading in the context's constructor (or by overriding [`OnModelCreating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating)):

```
public MyContext()
{
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: So if it doesn't work, you're gonna have to show us your code. Please share your `Contact` and `User` entities, your context, and your query.